# Como delimitar decimales en un gráfico de tabla pivot en Office Script?

Tags: typescript, excel, macros, office365, power-automate

Quisiera saber como delimitar el número de decimales que aparece en un gráfico de excel online mediante un script, este mismo script lo pienso utilizar en un flujo para optimizar los reportes en la empresa que trabajo. Para esto e hecho una tabla y de esa tabla e creado una tabla pivot con la cual se a generado este gráfico circular.

Esto es lo que tengo ahorita:
[image: Tabla Pivot con Gráfico Circular]

Lo que deseo es que aparezca el gráfico con valores de 149.92 horas aproximado a 2 decimales y 56.67 horas de esta manera se puede observar de mejor manera y puede aparecer el horas en la misma linea para una mejor visualización y orden.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
workbook.getWorksheet('DuraciónxAvance')?.delete();
// Add a new worksheet
let sheet1 = workbook.addWorksheet("DuraciónxAvance");
let oBRA = workbook.getTable("OBRA");
// Add a new pivot table on sheet1
let newPivotTable = workbook.addPivotTable("PivotTable3", oBRA, sheet1.getRange("A1:C18"));
// Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
newPivotTable.addRowHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Etapa"));
// Add pivot field to a hierarchy in newPivotTable
newPivotTable.addDataHierarchy(newPivotTable.getHierarchy("Duración"));
// Insert pivot chart on sheet sheet1
let chart_1 = sheet1.addChart(ExcelScript.ChartType.pie, newPivotTable.getLayout().getRange());

// Resize and move chart chart_1
chart_1.setLeft(218.25);
chart_1.setTop(0);
chart_1.setWidth(360);
chart_1.setHeight(216);
chart_1.getTitle().setText('Duración por Etapa');
chart_1.getSeries()[0].setHasDataLabels(true);
chart_1.getDataLabels().setShowPercentage(true);
chart_1.getDataLabels().setSeparator(" horas\n");
chart_1.getDataLabels().setPosition(ExcelScript.ChartDataLabelPosition.outsideEnd);

// Get images of the chart and table, then return them for a Power Automate flow.
const duracionxavanceImage = chart_1.getImage();
return {duracionxavanceImage};
}
// The interface for table and chart images.
interface ReportImages {
    duracionxavanceImage: string
}
```

Agradezco de antemano el apoyo brindado

Comment: Hola ¿Te refieres que al crear el gráfico dinámico solo deben tener dos decimales esos valores? Confirma y no olvides compartir tu código para que la ayuda sea basado en él.

Comment: Abraham que tal, es bueno volver a encontrate, si doctor, eso intento lograr, es el mismo grafico de la vez pasada, solo que ahora desdeo delimitarlo con 2 decimales, el grafico se genero con una tabla pivot

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por suerte @AbrahamValencia te ha ayudado con otra pregunta y tal vez tiene la información completa pero el resto de los usuarios no, por favor agrega un ejemplo completo.

Comment: Como ya te han dicho, e igual yo, es necesario ver tu código para ayudarte.

Comment: Disculpen la demora, estuve un poco ocupado estos días, ahi anexe el código de como cree la tabla pivot junto al gráfico para un mejor entendimiento del problema, agradezco su colaboración :D

Comment: Ah, ya, entendí mejor. Tienes un dilema, al igual que VBA con Excel de escritorio, TypeScript tiene las mismas limitaciones que las herramientas de Excel para la web. Si te das cuenta, en las etiquetas de datos de las series de los gráficos no hay formato numérico y por ende tampoco lo tiene en TypeScript. Necesariamente tienes que formatear las celdas de origen previamente para que eso se refleje en el gráfico.